# Perl: append a line after the last line that match a pattern (but incrementing part of the pattern)

Tags: perl

I've a file that contains a block of lines that look like this:

```
some lines

param.1=valueA
param.2=valueB
param.3=valueC

some other lines
```

I'm trying to find a perl one-liner to add right after the line `param.3` (well, the param with the highest number) a new line like `"param.4=valueD"`
I've tried several `"perl -i -pe"` command but haven't been able to perform it.
I pretty much want to replace the last match found of the line by itself + one new line in which I would increment a value.

example (in which I haven't found how to do the increment)

```
==#> cat /tmp/myfile.txt 
param.1=valueA 
param.2=valueB 
param.3=ValueC 
==#> perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/((param\.(\d+)=\S+\s+)*)/\1param.\3=newvalue\n/ms' /tmp/myfile.txt 
param.1=valueA 
param.2=valueB 
param.3=ValueC 
param.3=newvalue
```

Comment: Please show us some of the approaches you have taken.

Comment: example (in which I haven't found how to do the increment)

==#> cat /tmp/myfile.txt 
param.1=valueA
param.2=valueB
param.3=ValueC
==#> /usr/bin/perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/((param\.(\d+)=\S+\s+)*)/\1param.\3=newvalue\n/ms' /tmp/myfile.txt
param.1=valueA
param.2=valueB
param.3=ValueC
param.3=newvalue

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner? Things like this are better done in a small script. Chances are you'll be reusing it later.

Comment: `\1` `\2` `\3` etc. are not valid as backreferences in the right-hand-side of `s///`, use `$1` `$2` `$3` instead

Comment: It's for a product installation procedure.
I've figured a way to do it and will post it tomorrow from work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;}; s/((param\.(\d+)=\S+\s)+)/$1."param.".($3+1)."=valueXXX\n"/ems' /tmp/myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe '$matched = /^param\.(\d+)=value/ and $num = $1;
          $num and ! $matched
               and $_ = "param.$last=valueD\n$_"
               and undef $num;' myfile.txt
```

*"You want it on one line? Does it have to fit in 80 columns?"* -- Larry Wall