# Script to add line with part of the pattern used to find the line

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'd like to parse all *.php files, and for each line like

```
$res = $DB -> query($queryVar);
```

I need to get:

```
file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r($queryVar, TRUE));
$res = $DB -> query($queryVar);
```

The name of the variable $queryVar may change! I need to get it from the code!

My initial idea:

```
find  -not -path "*/\." -name "*.php" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's,SOMETHING,SOMETHING,'
```

but it seems to be not possible to get the name of the query variable with sed.

I also started looking at Perl: [Perl: append a line after the last line that match a pattern (but incrementing part of the pattern)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731078/perl-append-a-line-after-the-last-line-that-match-a-pattern-but-incrementing-p)

But I was able to do only this:

```
perl -pe 's/(-> query\(.*\))/AAAAA $1 AAAAA\n$1/'  < filename.php
```

With 2 problems: I get the result on standard output, I need something like sed to edit the original file, as I will call it from `find | xargs` and anyway I get the whole found line and not only the variable:

```
    $res = $DB AAAAA -> query( $SQL) AAAAA
-> query( $SQL);
```

Comment: Can't you just put the debug statement in one place, as the first line in the `query` function? Seems much easier than this approach.

Comment: Yes, but sometime query($query_to_exec) will be a custom function, some other times will be the standard mysqli function so I can't edit it! (tell me if I am wrong, just came back to php stuff) and as the code is not mine, I just need an automatic way to add debug info about queries in a simple way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file named `filename.php`, you can run the following command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.+-> query\((.+?)\).*)$/file_put_contents\("php:\/\/stderr", print_r\($2, TRUE\)\);\n$1/;' filename.php
```

It will update the file in-place with the substitution you intended to perform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl's `-i` flag to edit the file in place.

To only capture the query variable you need to add a capture group within the `()` part, as follows:

```
 perl -i -pe 's/^(.*-> query\((.*)\);)$/inserted_code_here($2);\n$1/' x.php
```

Then replace `inserted_code_here` with whatever you want to put on the line before the query call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `perl` like `sed`. But really, by doing so you throw away a lot of its potential as a language. I couldn't quite tell from your question - is `$queryVar` a literal, or is it a variable you need to replace?

Why not try this:

#!/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

sub process_php {
    next unless m/\.php$/;
    open( my $input, "<", $File::Find::name ) or warn $!;
    open( my $output, ">", $File::Find::name . ".new" )
        or warn $!;
    while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
        my ($query_id) = ( $line =~ m/-> query\((.*)\))/ );
        if ($query_id) {
            print {$output} "file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r(",
                $query_id, " TRUE));\n";
        }
        print {$output} $line;
    }
    close($input);
    close($output);
}

find( \&process_php, "/path/to/php/files" );
```

This will:

- search all the '*.php' files under the directory path.
- traverse them looking for your string.
- If it exists, add a new line just before it.
- write a '.new' file, with the new content (Once you're happy this works, you can swap 'em over).

Comment: didn't worked, I got: "my" variable $line masks earlier declaration in same statement at ./script.perl line 14.
"my" variable $line masks earlier declaration in same scope at ./script.perl line 19.
syntax error at ./script.perl line 13, near ") {"
syntax error at ./script.perl line 23, near "}"
Execution of ./script.perl aborted due to compilation errors.
Anyway, $queryVar is one of the possible names of the variable that contains the query that will be executed!

Comment: Oops, very minor typo. Fixed. This _should_ cope with extracting a 'variable name' rather than an actual argument. But it doesn't clobber the source, so it won't cause any harm either.